# Which event to bind my event handler to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

In my HTML, I have a table skeleton like this:

```
<table>
    <thead id="table-headings"></thead>
    <tbody id="table-body"></tbody>
</table>
```

Additionally, I have a `<div id="content"></div>` that will be used later on.

I fill the table body with rows and columns in a dynamic way using `$.ajax()` requests. Each cell in the table gets filled with a single `<a href="#">some link here</a>`. By clicking on one of the links, another `$.ajax()` request to the server is done and more data should be placed into `div#content`. Since the links were loaded dynamically, I use event delegation like so:

```
$('#table-body').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        // some settings here
        success: function(response) {
            // Append some data to the content div
            $('#content').append(...);
        }
    });    
});
```

All of this works fine. Now, here is the problem: Some of the data that I append to `div#content` is html source code surrounded by `<pre></pre>` tags. I want to highlight this source code using the [snippet jQuery syntax highlighting plugin](http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/). According to the event delegation rules, this should work in theory by doing:

```
$('#content').on('...', 'pre', function(event) {
    $(this).snippet('html');
});
```

My problem is, I don't know which JavaScript event I should bind my event handler to. Basically, I just want to highlight my code snippets once they have been loaded, but it seems there is no JavaScript event that fits here since jQuery's `load()` and `ready()` methods are meant for different purposes. What can I do to highlight my dynamically loaded html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$('#table-body').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        // some settings here
        success: function(response) {
            // Append some data to the content div
            $('#content').append(...);
            $('#content').find('pre').snippet('html');
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Awesome, this works fine. :) However, I would assume that putting the line `$('#content').find('pre').snippet('html');` out of the whole method block works as well. But it only works in the success handler of the `$.ajax()` call. Can you tell me why?

Comment: It works aswell, but it is more readable in my opinion :) I think you could write $('#content').('pre').snippet('html') aswell, but I'm at work and can't test this properly.

Comment: Oops, you are right. There was another mistake on my side. Anyway, thanks a lot, your solution works like a charm. :)

Comment: In the success handler the content is already appended to the DOM when find() is called, so it can be found. If you put it outside, it won't work because ajax is asynchronous, and the append action will happen most likely later than find('pre').

Comment: @Angel Exactly, this has come to my mind now as well. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any event for this... just use find to get `<pre>` tag in ajax success function
after the content is append..this way.. the DOM element will already be added to the document.. and will be able to find that

```
success:function(response){
  ....//your stuff;
  $('#content').find('pre').snippet('html');
 }
```

Comment: I thank you as well. :) But @lek0 was faster so I will accept that solution. +1 from me though. Good to know that `find()` also works for dynamically loaded selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
$('#table-body').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        // some settings here
        success: function(response) {
            // Append some data to the content div
            $newElemement=$(response)
            $('pre',$newElement).snippet('html')
            $('#content').append($newElement);
        }
    });    
});
```